# Why does the choice attribute (python) not work?

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to build a randomized greeting program, so far I got:

```
import random
a = ("Hi!", "How are you?", "You Good?")
b = random.choice(a)
print(b)
```

It used to work, but now it just says that there are no attributes for .choice, can someone help?

Edit1: I think my Python is broken...

Edit2: Wait it's fixed now...

Answer (score 1):

Rename your own script to something different than `random.py`.

Comment: The code is correct and works with python 2.7 >, tried it here https://repl.it/@p8ul/Random-choice#main.py.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Here are some step to refine or rebuild you code:

1. Rename the file and try again.
2. In `random.choice(a)`. `'a'` should be a `List, Tuple, or String` only.
3. try with square brackets `[]` instead of small bracket `()`. Like `a = ["Hi!", "How are you?", "You Good?"]`
4. Update your Python with the latest version.